# How i can detect Iphone and ipad separately using php

Tags: php

Is their any way to detect mobile browsers for iphone and ipad separately using PHP. I have used this code but iam getting same value for iphone and ipad

```
$isMobile = (bool)preg_match('#\b(ip(hone|od|ad)|android|opera m(ob|in)i|windows (phone|ce)|blackberry|tablet'.'|s(ymbian|eries60|amsung)|p(laybook|alm|rofile/midp|laystation portable)|nokia|fennec|htc[\-_]'.
'|mobile|up\.browser|[1-4][0-9]{2}x[1-4][0-9]{2})\b#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Tabs: `(bool)preg_match('#\b(ipad|tablet|up\.browser|[1-4][0-9]{2}x[1-4][0-9]{2})\b#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );`

For Phones: `bool)preg_match('#\b(ip(hone|od)|android|opera m(ob|in)i|windows (phone|ce)|blackberry'.'|s(ymbian|eries60|amsung)|p(laybook|alm|rofile/midp|laystation portable)|nokia|fennec|htc[\-_]'.'|mobile|up\.browser|[1-4][0-9]{2}x[1-4][0-9]{2})\b#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$isIPad = (false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'ipad'));
$isIPod = (false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'ipod'));
$isIPhone = (false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iphone'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try **[this class](http://codepad.org/pv6LSpjQ)**. It detects all types of mobile devices, iPad too (however I tested it only for Nokia, Android and iPhone).

```
if (UserAgentInfo::get()->DetectIpad()) {
    // iPad ...
} elseif (UserAgentInfo::get()->DetectIphone()) {
    // iPhone ...
} else {
    // Others ...
}
```

Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what action you will perform after detection is done. I will suggest you to look this article [iPad Detection Using JavaScript or PHP](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ipad) can find it useful, there are 3 ways to detect iphone/ipad device.